# Macbook with ubuntu installed shuts down randomly

Tags: shutdown, laptop, macbook, log, macosx

I installed Ubuntu on my Macbook. The Macbook shuts down randomly. It was the same problem with MacOS. I changed the SSD but the problem persists.

I followed some instructions on the web and I got an error code of 255 which stands for any other reason why the computer shuts down.

What could it be?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your description suggests that you have a hardware fault. Neither Ubuntu nor MacOS can fix hardware faults. You must get the hardware repaired or replaced.

Comment: If you had the same problem with two very different OSes, it is almost certainly a hardware problem, not a software problem.